# Prove $\langle k \rangle \big/ \langle n\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{(n/k)}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $\langle k \rangle$ and $\langle n \rangle$ are cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers).

Prove that $\langle k\rangle \big/ \langle n \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{(n/k)}$.

I am having trouble even starting this. 
The solution says that if $k$ divides $n$, then $\langle k\rangle \big/ \langle n \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n/k$. So it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{(n/k)}$. How is this true?

Comment: First, if $k\mathbb Z \supset n\mathbb Z$, that implies $k\vert n$. There is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to k\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ given by $x \mapsto kx$. What is the kernel?